# Snackbar no se muestra, evento clibk Button

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy usando navigation Componentes, y dentro de un fragment que tiene un button intento mostrar un Snackbar al evento click del button, aunque si se muetra el log cuando se clickea.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.prueba.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Hola: iniciciando", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //Snackbar.make(binding.root, "hola prueba magg", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.i("snackbar", "prueba de snackbar")
        })

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para hacer referencia a los widgets del fragment,  estoy usando viewBinding. Pareciera que ese es el problema

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que estas utilizando KOtlin....

si no te funciona prueba substituyendo el view del snackbar por

```
findViewById(R.id.layout principal del activity)
```

o sino  Prueba a ponerle en la expresión lambda el parámetro **View**, y  substituye esta expresion

```
   binding.prueba.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Hola: iniciciando", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            //Snackbar.make(binding.root, "hola prueba magg", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.i("snackbar", "prueba de snackbar")
    })
```

por esta otra expresion

```
  binding.prueba.setOnClickListener{ Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layout principal del activity), "Hola: iniciciando", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.i("snackbar", "prueba de snackbar")
        }
```

Comment: graicas, lo intente y no funciono

Comment: findViewById(R.id.layout principal del activity) den donde sale? en mi caso estoy usando Navigation Components, todos los fragments estan contenidos en una sola actividad

Answer (score 0):

La solucion que encontre fue basada en la documentacion material.io

```
https://material.io/components/snackbars/android#anatomy-and-key-properties
```

y debe quedar asi:

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Prueba estado", BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Como estoy usando el componente BottomNavigationView, para que se muestre el snackbar, se de usar `BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT`, en vez de `Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT`. Para mostrar un snackbar se debe mostrar dentro un CoordinatorLayout, asi como lo recomienda la documentación. Intente mostrarlo dentro de un ConstraitLayout y no fue posible en mi caso.

La verdad desconocia que cuando se usa un bottonNavigation, se debia usar esa propiedad en el Snackbar.  Gracias a **@iqanansoft** por los aportes que realizo, es posible que en otros contextos si funcione.